# How to modify a widget parent and after restore it?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to animate a widget that is **inside** a grid and a container, whenever hovered it is animated being expanded horizontally.

As the widget is inside of a container it gets cut because it cant expand above the parent widget area.

What I thought: when the widget is hovered, the code changes her parent to the `centralWidget` then it can expand above other widgets, and when it's no longer hovered restore her 'original' parent.

An example:

[image: dd166153-e65e-405a-9a61-77d46355f832-image.png]

As it could be seen in the gif below, before hovering:

The widget is 'attached' to the `GridLayout` and inside of the `Widget` container.

After the mouse leaves:

It's no longer attached to the `GridLayout` / `Widget`.

[image: 2022-10-08_16-35-49.gif]

I tried to 'restore' the widget to her parent with:

```
this->setParent(widgetParent);
```

But it didn't work or I may be doing something wrong.

I could not think of another way of doing all this (expanding a widget inside of a container above her parent limits), any different suggestion is welcome.

```
class AnimatedButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QPropertyAnimation* anim;

    struct WidgetPos { int x = 0; int y = 0; int w = 0; int h = 0;  };
    WidgetPos wp;
    QWidget* widgetParent;
    QWidget* centralwidget;

    void CreateAnimation(QByteArray propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "geometry")
        {
            anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this, propertyName);
            this->anim->setDuration(100);
            this->anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);

            this->wp.x = this->x();
            this->wp.y = this->y();
            this->wp.w = this->width();
            this->wp.h = this->height();
        }
    }



    AnimatedButton(QWidget* parent = 0) : QPushButton(parent)
    {  
        widgetParent = parent;
        this->installEventFilter(this);
    }



    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
    {
 
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            if (!this->wp.x)
                this->CreateAnimation("geometry");
             
            // setParent to the central widget so the widget can resize above her default parent area.
            this->setParent(this->centralwidget);
            this->show();

            this->anim->stop();
            this->anim->setStartValue(
                QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()));
            this->anim->setEndValue(
                QRect(this->x(), this->y(), (this->wp.w + 200) - this->width(), this->height()));
            this->anim->start();

        }
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave)
        {

            this->anim->stop();
            this->anim->setStartValue(
                QRect(this->x(), this->y(), (this->wp.w + 200) - this->width(), this->height()));
            this->anim->setEndValue(
                QRect(this->wp.x, this->wp.y, this->wp.w, this->wp.h));
            this->anim->start();
            
            // Restore default parent (--------NOT WORKING---------)
            this->setParent(widgetParent);
            this->show();

        }

        return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);       
    }
 
};


QtWidgetsApplication::QtWidgetsApplication(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    
    // Pass the central widget to the AnimatedButton class.
    ui.pushButton->centralwidget = ui.centralWidget;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Having `widgetParent = parent;` in your `AnimatedButton` constructor doesn't allow for the fact that the widget could be reparented elsewhere.  Instead try assigning `widgetParent = parentWidget();` immediately before `this->setParent(this->centralwidget);` in `AnimatedButton::eventFilter`.

Comment: @G.M. same thing.